# I regret my choice of grad school, is it possible/common to accept an offer I turned down a year ago?

Tags: graduate-school, health

I got accepted to three universities when I applied for grad school last year. There were two I was debating between and I chose one. Well, that was a HUGE mistake. The location is bad which I knew. I thought I would be able to handle that, but it's turning out that I can't...at all. The location is super depressing. There's nothing to do anywhere. Outside of my house there's always junkies hanging out shooting up. There was a meth lab around the corner that burned down. There is absolutely nothing to do, and the location is very far away from family. I couldn't see my family for some holidays which was very sad.

The location here is miserable, I honestly don't think I can handle another 5 years here.

I turned down another PhD offer, thinking I could handle this location. Well...I can't. The department here is ranked much higher than the other department. There's someone here I wanted to work with. But I don't even care about any of that if walking outside makes me miserable.

I don't care if none of my credits transfer. I don't care if I have to start over. I just can't handle this location. The only thing I don't want to go through again is applying and waiting to hear back, asking for letters of rec, etc.

I emailed the other department (who DID accept me last year, even with a fellowship) if there's anyway to transfer that doesn't require applying again.

Is this common? Is this possible? Or am I just stuck here or stuck reapplying?

Comment: I think you'll have to wait and see what they say.  But even if you have to reapply - if you were a good candidate before, and you've been reasonably successful in between, you will most likely be a good candidate again.

Comment: This is why you always need to do a campus visit -- and stay overnight with a current grad student in their housing.... :-(

Comment: If you emailed the other department to ask there, I don't understand the point of asking your question here.  They're the only ones that can give you a definitive answer (though it is very uncommon as RoboKaren says).

Comment: This is why universities should not be chosen solely on the basis of the ranking: daily life is important for serenity.

Comment: Why do you have to live in that particular house? You could move to a different part of town.

Comment: I've lived in some pretty terrible places (including with the meth labs burning down near by), but even in that particular place there were some less terrible areas that were still affordable. You might consider if there are less extreme alternatives to living in a nicer area, talk with people in your program about local clubs and groups that might have activities you had not heard about, etc. I'm not saying that moving won't be right for you - but I also know that moving across the country doesn't always make your problems go away. It's at least worth trying while you look at other options.

Answer (score 21):

There's almost a 100% certainty that you'll have to apply again. Graduate programs get a fixed number of admission slots (or fellowships to support those admits) each year. Your position was likely given away to someone or returned to the graduate school when you told them you weren't going.

As Nate Eldridge notes, you were a good candidate last year and you'll be a good candidate this year. There's a slight stain on your record regarding whether or not it was a personality conflict or something else that is causing you to abandon the other school.

If you have a good relationship with your current advisor, then s/he can address that in their letter of recommendation. Or you can ask your undergraduate advisors to note the reason why you're leaving the university.  The faculty on the admissions committee will be curious why you're leaving a more highly ranked program and admissions committees are risk-adverse, so you do need to address this somehow.